# Transfer all data files from internal memory to external SD card

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, file-transfer, motorola-moto-g3

I would like to know how to transfer entire internal drive to external micro SD card on  the Motorola Moto G 3rd Gen?

The reason is my phone is saying it can't update because there is no space left. So I bought an SD card of 4GB in size. But even after transferring what it said it did, it still was not enough. The SD card only show kb. Had been transferred over and that didn't make sense. So maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Hi! I changed the tone from asking possibility to the one seeking a method, because given the rest of the body, I believe you would like to know one. Feel free to [edit] out the changes if I strayed away from your original intent.

Answer (score -1):

You can transfer files like audio,video and pictures and small portion of your downloaded app(as i can on my sony xperia e3). But you cannot move all of your app data to SD card. In order to do that you have to root your phone(it is quite risky if you haven't done that before).

Comment: "*But you cannot move all of your app data to SD card. In order to do that you have to root your phone*" -- why so? Please explain. We expect detailed answers here. Read [How do I write a good answer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)